# Transparent status bar in only one page

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to set the status bar on just one screen of my app as transparent. The problem is that when I navigate to another screen, even trying to set the status bar back to its original color, it remains transparent.
Has anyone here ever had to deal with this situation?

Navigating from 1 -> 2 -> 3

At screen 1 and 3:

`SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle( statusBarColor: AppColors.primary, ));`

At screen 2:

`SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle( statusBarColor: Colors.transparent, ));`

Scren 3 remains transparent

Comment: show us your code

Answer (score 1):

Try to use widget `AnnotatedRegion` as wrapper for specific pages instead using of `SystemChrome` call.